# How to retrieve data from table with conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am developing to database view in mysql server to get status of the grns by joining grns to comment table. I want to display grn is rejected or approved. There may be several comments for single grns on comment table.

If there is single "Approval" for grn in comment table status of the grn must be return as "Approved",otherwise "Rejected" Or "Pending" Here is the dummy of two tables.

[image: grn and comment tables]

expected results:

```
G1 - rejected
G2 - approved
G3 - approved
G4 - approved
G5 - approved
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a test whether rows exist in `comment` with either `approved` or `rejected` status for each `grn-no` value. If a `grn` is neither approved or rejected, the status is set to `pending`.

```
SELECT g.`grn-no`,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM comment c WHERE c.grn_id = g.id AND c.status = 'approved') THEN 'approved'
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM comment c WHERE c.grn_id = g.id AND c.status = 'rejected') THEN 'rejected'
            ELSE 'pending' END AS status
FROM grn g
```

Output:

```
grn-no  status
G1      rejected
G2      approved
G3      approved
G4      approved
G5      approved
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8b4075022ac992b295bebfb8cbbc57c9)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `correlated subquery`

```
select concat(grn_no,
              ' - ',
              coalesce((select status
                         from comment
                        where status = 'approved'
                          and grn_id = g.id
                        group by grn_id),
                       'rejected')) "Result"
  from grn g
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2a6733d8af89b8e4dcbb57ec20660c03)</kbd>

Comment: How does this deal with the `pending` case?

Comment: @Nick Question tells us `...otherwise "Rejected" Or "Pending"...`, and I preferred one of them.

Comment: I took that to mean it was possible for there to be a 'pending' state as well as 'rejected'. For example, if a `grn` only had a `concession` status

Comment: @Nick well, your assumption goes like that :)

Comment: I guess time will tell whose assumption is valid! :)

Comment: @Nick - Thanks both, we can modify above like this                                           select concat(grn_no,' - ',
   coalesce((select status from comments
    where status = 'approved' and grn_id = g.id group by grn_id),
    (select status from comments
    where status = 'rejected' and grn_id = g.id group by grn_id),
    'pending')) "Result"
from grns g;

Comment: @MD40 you're welcome friend, we were guessing how style we should bring the results :). Btw prefer sharing text data as sample output for your future questions please. Easier to manipulate them rather than pictures.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan -I can understand what you are saying, I'll follow the instructions from next time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `group_concat(flatten)` function

```
Select
`grn-no`, 
Case when status like ('%approved%') then 'approved' else 'rejected' end as status 
From
(Select  
`grn-no`, 
 group_concat(status) as status 
 From grn 
 left join comment 
 on grn.id = comment.grn_id  
 group by 1) a
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found all the functions following above code. Above question was to develop the database view in below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW summery AS

    SELECT
    g.id,
    g.supply_date,
    g.grn_no,
    COUNT(b.bag_no) AS bags,
    CONCAT(s.fname," ", s.lname) AS name,
    SUM(b.weight) AS qty,
    AVG(b.bag_mc) AS mc,
    (g.dust_initial/g.dust_weight)*100 AS dust,
    (g.ubs_initial/g.ubs_weight)*100 AS ubs,
    p.fraction_1 AS fraction_1,
       CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM comments c WHERE c.grn_id = g.id AND c.status = 'approved') THEN 'Approved'
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM comments c WHERE c.grn_id = g.id AND c.status = 'approved with concession') THEN 'Approved with Concession'
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM comments c WHERE c.grn_id = g.id AND c.status = 'concession required') THEN 'Concession Required'
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM comments c WHERE c.grn_id = g.id AND c.status = 'rejected') THEN 'Rejected'
       ELSE 'pending' END AS status
FROM grns g
    JOIN suppliers s ON s.id = g.supplier_id
    JOIN psds p ON g.id = p.grn_id
    JOIN bags b ON g.id = b.grn_id
GROUP BY g.id
ORDER BY g.id DESC
```